# Convert this=that style controller to $scope variables in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using an autocomplete package `angular-auto-complete` and the controller example is written in what seems and outdated style with `that = this` definition instead of `$scope`. This is the current working code:

```js
app.controller('autocompleteCtrl', autocompleteCtrl);

    autocompleteCtrl.$inject = ['$http'];
    function autocompleteCtrl($http) {
        var that = this;
        that.stateName = null;

        that.autoCompleteOptions = {
            minimumChars: 2,
            data: function (term) {
                return $http.get('coinMarketList.json')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // ideally filtering should be done on server
                      term = term.toUpperCase();
                        var match = _.filter(response.data, function (value) {
                            return value.longName.toUpperCase().includes(term);
                        });
                        return _.pluck(match, 'longName');
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm attempting to convert it like this:

```js
app.controller('autocompleteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.stateName = null;

        $scope.autoCompleteOptions = {
            minimumChars: 2,
            data: function (term) {
                return $http.get('coinMarketList.json')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // ideally filtering should be done on server
                      term = term.toUpperCase();
                        var match = _.filter(response.data, function (value) {
                            return value.longName.toUpperCase().includes(term);
                        });
                        return _.pluck(match, 'longName');
                    });
            }
        }
    }])
```

However this breaks the code, and the console isn't giving me an errors. How can I properly convert this to `$scope` variables?

Comment: The `Controller As` style is most certainly not "outdated"  (see [John Papa's Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-view-syntax), updated Aug 15 2017, Angular Team Endorsed: );  However, converting between them isn't extremely difficult, assuming you made the correct changes in the HTML file as well, which isn't knowable since you haven't shown those changes here.....

Comment: how are u passing `autoCompleteOptions` to angular-auto-complete?

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round. It's the `$scope` syntax that's considered outdated - or bad practice, compared to using `this`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I needed to change the HTML. That's what I was missing